# PHP combine 2 arrays into a third

Tags: php, arrays

Given 2 arrays in PHP that look like this...

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [myValues] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 1
                )

        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [myValues] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 1
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 1
        )

)

array1
array ( 'item1' => array ( 'myValues' => array ( 1 => 5, 2 => 1, ), ), 'item2' => array ( 'myValues' => array ( 1 => 5, 2 => 1, ), ), )
```

What is the best way to combine them into an array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [myValues] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 1
                )
            [myValues2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [myValues] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 1
                )
            [myValues2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 1
                )

        )

)

array2
array ( 'item1' => array ( 1 => 2, ), 'item2' => array ( 1 => 5, 2 => 1, ), )
```

I have no control over the output so I am thinking my best approach would be to loop over each array and copy the items into a fresh one.

I have tried...

```
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

But this is not giving me the result I am looking for. Does anybody have an example?

Comment: Please always present your array data as `var_export ()`.  I can't bring myself to rewrite your arrays on 3v4l.org on my phone.  Since `array_merge()` obviously wouldn't work as required, what research did you do, how did you change your first coding attempt to try to solve?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not following. Is this not the best way to present my arrays?

Comment: I cannot copy-paste your input into a testing environment when you use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`. This means I have to waste time preparing your data before I can begin writing my suggested solution.  Please edit.

Comment: Have added var_export versions to each, does that make things more straightforward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push your array2 data into array1 by using the known first level key and your invented second level key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VFvJG))

```
$array1 = array ( 'item1' => array ( 'myValues' => array ( 1 => 5, 2 => 1, ), ), 'item2' => array ( 'myValues' => array ( 1 => 5, 2 => 1, ), ), );
$array2 = array ( 'item1' => array ( 1 => 2, ), 'item2' => array ( 1 => 5, 2 => 1, ), );

foreach ($array2 as $key => $subarray) {
    $array1[$key]['myValues2'] = $subarray;
}

var_export($array1);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'item1' => 
  array (
    'myValues' => 
    array (
      1 => 5,
      2 => 1,
    ),
    'myValues2' => 
    array (
      1 => 2,
    ),
  ),
  'item2' => 
  array (
    'myValues' => 
    array (
      1 => 5,
      2 => 1,
    ),
    'myValues2' => 
    array (
      1 => 5,
      2 => 1,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I would never have gotten that without your help. Thanks also for the description, it really helped me understand what was happening in the code

Comment: I disagree.  I believe you could have self-solved this problem.  Please believe in yourself and show more perseverance before asking for help -- this will make you a better developer.